# Different website when accessing http and www

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, g-suite, google-app-engine

I am trying to configure our website and currently, we have two versions of it:

1. Old website (v1) which uses http:// (without www.)
2. New Website (v2) which uses http://www.

I am a beginner at this and im scared to delete records in my admin profile because we really need the website to work but if by mistake, I delete a vital record, it is hard for me to fix things because I am not knowledgeable with Google Cloud. Here is the record set page:

[image]

---

[image]

What I want to happen is to remove the http://pointblue.ph or at least redirect it to www.pointblue.ph. Any leads?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add "pointblue.ph" to www.pointblue.ph's list of allowed domains on the server. Once you do that you can change the DNS of pointblue.ph to be a CNAME for storage.l.googleusercontent.com.

Here's how you tell if this is done correctly:

```
# nc www.pointblue.ph 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: pointblue.ph

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
<other response headers from the server>
```

Once this is setup the following will happen:

```
# nc www.pointblue.ph 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: pointblue.ph


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If you try setting Host: www.pointblue.ph you'll see your webpage's html.

If you're worried this might not work correctly, there's something easier you can probably setup. Instead of the above, you can also redirect pointblue.ph to www.pointblue.ph. I don't know how to set this up with Google (Pages?), but almost every kind of webhost account has this ability. For a professional website you'll need the website for pointblue.ph to give a "301" or "302" redirect, which will quickly and transparently redirect the browser to load the www.* site instead.

It'd probably be worth getting a non-google hosted account if you can't set this up with Google's hosting.

Comment: The program nc is almost the same as the telnet command.